# Assign variable to MXML component ID

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml, flex4.5

I have my custom component and for example few Label. I want to pass to my component value which will be assign to label's id.

Code:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Inspectable]
            [Bindable]
            public var test:String = "asd";
        ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label id="{test}" text="etc"/>
```

Error: {test} is not a valid identifier

Can I even do something like that?

Comment: Can I ask why? what's the point of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't. You have to understand that when you write an mxml component like

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Label id="myLabel" />
</s:Group>
```

it will generate ActionScript code like

```
public class MyClass extends Group {
    public var myLabel:Label;
}
```

(Mind you, I grossly oversimplify the code here to convey the most important part).

As you can see your 'id' is in fact a property name. And you can't change a property's name at runtime can you?

Comment: I had hope, that maybe there's some way to dynamically generate property's name - I knew one language that it is possible. But unfortunately not here.

Thanks for help!