# Flex reference child element

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can we reference to an element which is added dynamically on runtime?

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            trace(button1.label);

            var newbtn:Button = new Button();
            newbtn.label = "New Button";
            newbtn.id = "button3";
            newbtn.name = "button3";

            mygroup.addElement(newbtn);

            trace(this["button3"].label);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HGroup id="mygroup">
    <s:Button id="button1" label="Button 1" />
    <s:Button id="button2" label="Button 2" />
</s:HGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

When I try to run above code, it dispatch error

```
Error #1069: Property button3 not found on project1 and there is no default value.
```

So, how can I call to the newly added button?

Comment: Please try setting the `name` property to "button3" as well. Not 100% sure I remember but it may do the trick.

Comment: Can't you use `getChildByName`?

Comment: try with updatecomplete instead of applicationcomplete

Comment: `button3` is locally scoped to the `init` method; it does not belong to the class (i.e. `this`). Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632854/unable-to-retrieve-property-in-main-from-child-popup-using-event-in-flashbuilder) I just wrote; it's the exact same issue. That said, you hardly ever need to 'dynamically' add components to the stage in a Flex application. You should probably be using List/DataGroup or states instead, depending on your use case.

Comment: OK. Just noticed you tried to assign `id` through actionscript. It doesn't work like that. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533585/assign-variable-to-mxml-component-id/6533656#6533656

Comment: getChildByName is meant to make the Flash Pro IDE easier to use, and has no place in a proper Flex application.

Answer (score 0):

Store your instance in a variable and reference it whenever you feel like it. Use an array for a list of variables.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using

var obj = this.getChildByName("button3");

after that you can use obj to trace the label

Comment: Don't use getChildByName in Flex. Just use proper Actionscript.

Comment: can you please explain why someone should not use "getChildByName" in flex ? i use it often !!!!

Comment: getChildByName makes a lot more sense when working in the Flash IDE as the environment tends to require a lot of string manipulation for referencing instances (EG. button1, button2, etc.). However, this programming construct is hugely inefficient and prone to error (in other words, bad practice). In a proper Actionscript or Flex project, this technique should only be used as a last resort. Rather one should use proper programming constructs to reference instances of DisplayObject.